# Can you iterate over object properties in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, loop

I know you can use the `for:each` directive to loop through Arrays, but is there some way to loop through an object's properties?

Comment: No, you need to convert that into an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot. However, it is pretty easy to do so with a getter:

```
get objectProperties() {
  return Object.entries(this.recordObject).map(([key,value])=>({ key, value }));
}
```

...

```
for:each={objectProperties} for:item="prop"
```